# Querying dependent views via ODBC

Tags: mysql, sql, odbc

I'm using the CData ODBC driver for Authorize.net... trying to get a list of transactions with detail. There are three tables:

- SettledBatchList
- TransactionList
- TransactionDetails

I can't get the TransactionList without specifying a BatchID from SettledBatchList. I can't get the TransactionDetails without specifying the TransID from the TransactionList.

It's a nested mess! I tried this to no avail.

```
select TransactionList.*, TransactionDetails.Description
from TransactionList
left join TransactionDetails on TransactionDetails.TransID = TransactionList.TransID
where TransactionList.BatchID in ( select BATCHID from SettledBatchList )
```

There's limited documentation here: http://cdn.cdata.com/help/CWF/odbc/pg_allviews.htm

Comment: Joining 3 tables is far from a mess and it is not obvious why your query does not work. So why? Also post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Comment: I'm just looking to pull everything from TransactionList with Description field from TransactionDetails. Authorize.net requires BatchID from SettledBatchList in order to pull the transactions.

Comment: This query works... but adding the third table kills it.

select TransactionList.*
from TransactionList
where TransactionList.BatchID in ( select BATCHID from SettledBatchList )

Comment: What is the problem with your query?

Comment: DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [HY000] TransId must be specified to retrieve the details for a transaction.
Details:
    DataSourceKind=Odbc
    DataSourcePath=dsn=CData AuthorizeNet Source
    OdbcErrors=[Table]